# How to add select effect to an image button?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

What I am trying to implement: I want to have four image buttons that if I click on one button then there will be a little check mark displayed showing that I select the check mark. And if I click on another button, then the check mark of the previous button will disappear and my newly selected button will show a little check mark.

The code I currently have:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  Margin="20, 80">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="120" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="120" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ImageButton Source="select_payment_placeholder.png"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Grid.Column="0" />
                <ImageButton Source="select_payment_placeholder.png"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Grid.Column="1" />
                <ImageButton Source="select_payment_placeholder.png"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.Column="0" />
                <ImageButton Source="select_payment_placeholder.png"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
```

This is the demo of the effect that I am trying to implement.

[image]

Comment: Hi , there is a solution that you can custom a ContentView that contains the ImageButton and MarkIcon , and bind with proper ViewModel when used . When selcected item changes , the model will change data to update View .

Comment: I have updated an answer , you can have a look at that when have time . If answer be helpful , remember to mark or vote it up :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I used the **[Xamarin.Forms CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/)** as the parent layout .

Create the **CheckItem** :

```
public class CheckItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string ContentImage { set; get; }

    private bool isShow;

    public bool IsShow
    {
        set
        {
            if (isShow != value)
            {
                isShow = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsShow");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return isShow;
        }
    }

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {
                var item = (e as CheckItem);
                // logic on item
                if (item.isShow)
                {
                    PageMain.checkItems[0].IsShow = false;
                    PageMain.checkItems.Remove(PageMain.checkItems[0]);
                    PageMain.checkItems.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    item.IsShow = true;
                    if (PageMain.checkItems.Count == 0)
                    {
                        PageMain.checkItems.Add(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PageMain.checkItems[0].IsShow = false;
                        PageMain.checkItems.Remove(PageMain.checkItems[0]);
                        PageMain.checkItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
               
            });
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then the **CheckModel** can be set a list data with four item :

```
public class CheckModel
{

    public List<CheckItem> CheckItems { set; get; }

    public CheckModel()
    {
        CheckItems = new List<CheckItem>();
        CheckItems.Add( new CheckItem() { ContentImage = "XamarinLogo.png", IsShow = false});
        CheckItems.Add( new CheckItem() { ContentImage = "XamarinLogo.png", IsShow = false});
        CheckItems.Add( new CheckItem() { ContentImage = "XamarinLogo.png", IsShow = false});
        CheckItems.Add( new CheckItem() { ContentImage = "XamarinLogo.png", IsShow = false});
    }
}
```

In the **ContentPage** , the Xaml code contains a `CollectionView` and which contains the `ImageButton` and `MarkIcon` . And the `MarkIcon` default is `invisible` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="ImageButonSingleCheck.PageMain">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="Start" 
                HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            <CollectionView x:Name="MyCollectionView"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CheckItems}"
                            SelectionMode="None"
                            SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                     Span="2" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RelativeLayout x:Name="Item" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="120">
                            <ImageButton x:Name="MyImageButton"
                                         BackgroundColor="LightYellow"
                                         Source="{Binding ContentImage}"
                                         Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}"
                                         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.15,Constant=0}"
                                         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                                         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.8,Constant=0}" />
                            <Image x:Name="CheckImage"
                                   Source="Tick.png"
                                   BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                                   IsVisible="{Binding IsShow}"
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=MyImageButton,Property=Y,Factor=1,Constant=5}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=MyImageButton,Property=X,Factor=1,Constant=150}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=40}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=40}" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In **ContentPage** , invoked the CheckModel :

```
public partial class PageMain : ContentPage
{
    CheckModel checkModel;
    public static List<CheckItem> checkItems  { set; get; }
    public PageMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkModel = new CheckModel();
        BindingContext = checkModel;

        checkItems = new List<CheckItem>();
    }
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Here is [the Sample](https://github.com/john-heaven/ImageButonSingleCheck) .